# redirect to SSL with the exception of one URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I run a small [bootstrap themes](http://bootstrapcovers.com) site that allows users to upload themes and templates.

I've been able to redirect any non SSL connection to https via my .htaccess file with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I now need to redirect the user to non-SSL for one page in particular.  It's a page containing an iframe that loads a preview from the theme authors site and these sites aren't always served via SSL.

The URL always has the word 'preview' preceded by the domin.

Here's is what I've tried, unfortunately without success:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/preview [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/preview [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```

Here are two examples:

**non-preview link**:
http://www.bootstrapcovers.com/bootstrap-themes/all/free/sort.downloads/page.1

**preview link**
http://www.bootstrapcovers.com/preview/1/adminlte-admin-control-panel

Any idea why it's not working or what I'm missing from the .htaccess file?

Thanks,
-Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` which might change due to other modules or rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+preview [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+preview [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

# other rules go here
```

Also make sure to clear your browser cache.

Comment: excellent, that worked! What is the difference between REQUEST_URI and THE_REQUEST?

Comment: `THE_REQUEST` is original web request that is received by Apache from clients and it doesn't change due to other rules.

Comment: great to know...thanks again for the help. I spent way too many hours on this :)