# redirecting a long URL to https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

After resolving my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377357/redirect-to-ssl-with-the-exception-of-one-url) for avoiding a redirect for a specific portion of a URL I'm now trying to solve an issue of redirecting a long, more complex URL to https

This is the line in my .htaccess file giving me issues:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

index.php is never exposed in the URL itself. For instance this URL should redirect to https:

[http://bootstrapcovers.com/themes/bootstrap-themes/toolsmith-1110/volvox-responsive-html5-bootstrap-template](https://bootstrapcovers.com/themes/bootstrap-themes/toolsmith-1110/volvox-responsive-html5-bootstrap-template)

After entering the URL it's redirected to:

```
[https://bootstrapcovers.com/index.php?uri=themes/bootstrap-themes/toolsmith-1110/volvox-responsive-html5-bootstrap-template][2]
```

Notice that **index.php?uri=** is added which I would expect but the page is redirecetd back to the home page. If I remove that portion (index.php?uri=) the url works!

How can I redirect the URL without the addition of **index.php?uri=**?

Here is my complete .htaccess file:

```
# 1 Month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico|woff)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+preview [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+preview [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
-Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a reorder and bit of refactoring of your rules. Have it this way:

```
# 1 Month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico|woff)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+preview [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+preview [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: anubhava, I don't have a uri argument in my URLs...is this even neccessary? Thanks for the feedback

Comment: But I didn't mention `url argument` anywhere in my answer. My answer if for this requirement you wrote: `How can I redirect the URL without the addition of index.php?uri=?` Did you test the changes I suggested after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: I did test your changes and everything works great. When I remove the last entry in the .htaccess file it fails. None of my URLs use this format (index.php?uri=) so I guess I don't understand why it fails...